# Hibernate Annotation Join table question

Tags: hibernate

When doing join table with hibernate annotation, how to i add an extra column that's not a join column, like, say married as a weak entity? like an extra column?

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=some.class,
        cascade ={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "RELATION", joinColumns ={
        @JoinColumn(name = "HID", unique = true)
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "FID")
})
Set<PERSON> PEOPLE = new HashSet<PERSON>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A third column technically makes that table an entity, not a "jointable". So the table would need to be an entity itself. Think about it from a SQL point of view. Is a join table just a join table when it has more than just the info needed to join two other tables together?

Also as FYI, this scenario is covered in chapter 7 of "Java Persistence (JPA) with Hibernate":

> You can use two common strategies to map such a structure to Java classes. The 
>   first strategy requires an intermediate entity class for the join table and is mapped 
>   with one-to-many associations. The second strategy utilizes a collection of components, with a value-type class for the join table.

Comment: Specifically, that's section 7.2.3 of the book.